# Strange syntax in CImg library, don't know what it's called

Tags: c++, function, cimg

I've been using CImg to generate some images, but I've come across a strange syntax and I don't know what it's called.  It allows you to do something like this:

```
cimg_forXYC(image, x, y, z){
    // I can set things about the image here
    image(x, y, z) = 100.;
}
```

I've never come across this kind of weird user-defined custom-style function before.  What is it called, and how is it created?

Comment: What?  I'm talking about the fact that I didn't define the cimg_forXYC function, but can write its body anyways.  I know that that converts to a float.  Can you tell me which part of my question was ambiguous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cimg_forXYC` is a [macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) that roughly replaces a `for` loop and it is used to loop over image dimensions:

```
cimg_forXYC(img,x,y,v) : equivalent to : cimg_forC(img,v) cimg_forXY(img,x,y)
```

and

```
cimg_forC(img,v) : equivalent to : for (int v = 0; v<img.spectrum(); v++)
cimg_forXY(img,x,y) : equivalent to : cimg_forY(img,y) cimg_forX(img,x)
```

and finally

```
cimg_forX(img,x) : equivalent to : for (int x = 0; x<img.width(); x++)
```

If you [check the documentation](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__loops.html), you'll see all details.

Your `image.operator()(int, int, int)` returns a reference, so you can use it the way you do.

Comment: So `cimg_forX(img, x)` gets replaced with `for(int x = 0; x<img.width(); x++)`, and so on for more dimensions?

Comment: @theStandard precisely! It is blindly replaced by the preprocessor with the corresponding text (in this case the `for` loops).

Comment: Thank you, I'll mark your answer as correct and remove this comment (as I see they're discouraged) as soon as I can.

Comment: @theStandard comments are OK, it is usually discouraged to discuss too much or to post answers in a comment. Requiring clarifications is just fine.

Comment: @theStandard yeah, that's true :)